# How do I compute the angle needed to have a turning radius of $<8m$ and its wheel base with 20'' tire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I was doing a project of  a vehicle, I'm assigend to the steering. I need to have a turning radius of $<8m$ however I'm limiting my space for the wheels. I've read that $>$ wheel base $=$ $>$ turning radius. I was thinking searching for a formula but couldn't find one. I also know the [Ackermann's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_steering_geometry). I need to know the angle needed to have $<8m$ and also the space that it would occupy for my wheel base. I'm using a $20'$ bicycle tire

Answer (score 1):

Draw the geometry of the problem, like I have below, and the answer should become clear. There is not one angle, but two different ones $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ for a conventional steering mechanism.  The Ackermann mechanism theoretically has the rotational axes of both forward wheels meeting the axis defined by the hinder wheel axle at the same point $C$ so that the car is steering about the point $C$. I discuss these ideas in the general introduction to my discussion of the Lie theoretical description of parallel car parking on [my website here](http://www.wetsavannaanimals.net/wordpress/parallel-parking-a-car/). Note that actual steering can be quite different from the Ackermann condition and, depending on the application, some slipping of the tyres can be deliberately designed for.

[image: Car Parking Geometry]